# how to generate thumbnail image of a video using flowplayer?

Tags: flowplayer

We can use a png image as the first screen of a video. Can flowplayer generate or create an image based on the video and use it as thumbnail image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it can't. This is caused by the fact, that Flowplayer is a player. The better practice is to get the thumbnail in another way (maybe as described [here in Flowplayer docs](http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/generating-thumbs.html)) and display it as splash image (described [here in Flowplayer docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/splash-image.html)) or as first item of a playlist (described [here in Flowplayer docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/playlist-splash.html)).

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"Moved | Apologies! | We couldn't find what you're looking for."*